# Symfony custom form field type FQCN to store in a database field

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony4

I'm in the process of migration a symfony 2.8 application to 3.4 and then to 4.1. As you know `::getName()` of a custom form field type had become deprecated and was removed in 2.8 and 3.x respectively. So now one need to specify a FQCN when adding a custom field to the form. The problem is that we have a `Settings` table with a set or rows representing form fields. Each row of this type in the DB table has its own field type (a column in the DB table). So it looks like:

```
'4', '1', NULL, 'password_expiration', '365', 'integer', 'Period of user password expiration, in days', 'Password Expiration'
'6', '1', NULL, 'login_min_length', '3', 'integer', 'Minimum allowable login length', 'Login Minimum Length'
....
'17', '1', NULL, 'help_page', '', 'ckeditor', 'Help page content for users', 'Help page'
```

where `integer` and `ckeditor` are the values used to be passed as custom or native symfony field type name into the `::add()` call of a form.

As you can imagine it throws an exception `Could not load type "ckeditor": class does not exist` under 3.4, because I need to refer to a FQCN of `MyBundle\Form\Type\CkEditorType::class` somehow. But even if I update the database field values to something like 'MyBundle\Form\Type\CkEditorType::class' (with properly escaped backslashes, obviously) it will be interpreted as string and not eval'ed.

So the question is: how do we store FQCN in a database field and interpret it when rendering a form?

Comment: You could write a function to translate the strings from your database: function getClass($string) { if ($string == 'ckeditor') { return MyBundle\Form\Type\CkEditorType::class; } }

Comment: yes, that's clear, but it's a kind of "proxy"-solution. I was under impression some people store their form configs in databases along with form field types, so should be a typical task